# External Style Sheet

Tags: php, html, css, stylesheet

I've created an CSS external style sheet for a webpage of my website.  I have uploaded it to the server and have used the following code in my PHP file to load the webpage. However, the webpage just loads as if it ignores the style sheet. Here's the code in the PHP file that I have used so I just uploaded the HTML tags here. Any help would be a great help.  Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<link  rel="styleshhet" type="text/css" href="/webspace/httpdocs/new_select3_style_sheet.css">
<script>function goBack() {window.history.back()}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use a server path, use a relative path. I.e.: if in root `href="/new_select3_style_sheet.css">` and typo in `styleshhet` which should read as `stylesheet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link  rel="styleshhet" type="text/css" href="/webspace/httpdocs/new_select3_style_sheet.css">
```

goes to:

```
 <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new_select3_style_sheet.css">
```

First you had a typo -> `stylesheet` not `stylshhet` second all paths run from above httpdocs in public facing HTML (where your site will be) so you need to remove everything above that! e.g.

```
/webspace/httpdocs/new_select3_style_sheet.css
```

If your domain was `example.com` then `/webspace/httpdocs/` = `example.com/` when building URLs

Comment: Thank you. I should have noticed the typo. I'm an amateur at this so thank you for your help.

Comment: no problem - if the answer fixed your problem please click the up arrow t0 +1 it and accept the answer by pressing the tick. We all started somewhere - once you get it it is easy I promise!!

Comment: will do, i do not have a high enough reputation at the moment to +1 the answer but i will press the tick. thanks again.